# Swift 2 - Using a Set as value type in a dictionary

Tags: ios, dictionary, set, swift2

I'm new to Swift/iOS and I have trouble using Sets in a dictionary. I have the following Code:

```
internal let attributeLists = Dictionary<String,Set<String>>()

public func getAttributeList(name: String) -> Set<String> {
        if self.attributeLists[name] == nil{
            self.attributeLists[name] = Set<String>()
        }
        return self.attributeLists[name]!
}
```

The compiler gives me an error at `self.attributeLists[name] = Set<String>()`

It says **Cannot assign to the result of this expression**.

It'm wondering if it has something to do with optionality.
When i use `self.attributeLists.updateValue(value: Set<String>(), forKey: name)` it will give me the error: `Immutable value of type Dictionary<String,Set<String>> only has mutating members named updateValue`

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `attributeLists` with `let`, which means it is a constant and immutable empty dictionary.